# Linux Copiar arquivo dando replace no conteúdo

Tags: linux, shell-script

como poderia ser feito para que eu copie via shell script um arquivo php, porem substituindo o conteudo de uma variável?

Exemplo: cat config-sample.php > config.php

```
<?php $senha="[dados_a_ser_substituido]";?>
```

Comment: E não pode criar um arquivo php de terminal com `var_export();` para alterar o valor das variaveis?

Comment: Poderia, sabe me informar qual seria a sintaxe para isso ou onde obter essa informação?

Comment: Eu costumo usar o comando sed, no seu caso depois de copiar o arquivo tente este comando:  

`sed -i 's/<?php $senha=".*;?>/<?php $senha="dados_que_eu_desejo";?>/g' config.php`

Comment: Miguel Funcionou perfeitamente, existe alguma forma de dar 2 ou mais replaces na mesma linha?